# Change the complete KDE Desktop Look like a Theme?

Tags: kde, themes, customization

Is there any application to change the complete look of KDE like a theme in gnome? 
Without changing the colors, icons, styles, backgrounds, decorators and so forth individually but in one process instead?

Something like a theme manager?

I would like to create a complete KDE Desktop look & style and then share it with friends without setting up 8 sets of settings with all kinds of importing files and setups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a KDE4 desktop theme manager in the advanced tab of the settings panel. But if you need to change things outside of that then you need to talk with the kde developers in order to make something more complete and cohesive. So far people on http://kde-look.org/ probably have the most advanced ideas on how to publish and deploy entire themes.

Anything they don't know, probably doesn't exist.

Comment: No, this advanced tab is not what I'm talking about. It only changes the so called "desktop theme". I'm talking about "theme" like in gnome which takes care of panel, system colors, apllication colors, windows decorations ... - the complete look & feel. The Kde way of setting up the whole appearance is just a pain, you have to go to 8 different places in the settings (maybe more) and set every aspect individually.

Comment: Right, and in that case you have to go to the kde developers and get the problem fixed in the code.